# 3,5" LCD display not work in raspberry pi

Tags: spi, pitft, lcd

I have bought a 3,5" display from [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/3-5-Inch-LCD-Display-Touch-Screen-Kit-w-Case-Heatsink-for-Raspberry-Pi2-Pi3/252943075467?hash=item3ae495088b:g:uHAAAOSwTw5bjNzJ), and I installed it onto my raspberry pi 3.

I installed the [LCDshow](https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git) drivers, but when it restarts the display is white.

I tried to start the gui, but it gives:

```
sudo startx

X.Org X Server 1.19.2
Release Date: 2017-03-02
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.41-v7+ armv7l Raspbian
Current Operating System: Linux pi3-master 4.14.50-v7+ #1122 SMP Tue Jun 19 12:26:26 BST 2018 armv7l
Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=480 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=320 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:ProFont6x11 logo.nologo
Build Date: 18 October 2017  04:55:30PM
xorg-server 2:1.19.2-1+rpt1+deb9u2 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Sep  8 15:56:59 2018
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
```

log:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[   243.257] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.2
Release Date: 2017-03-02
[   243.258] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   243.258] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.41-v7+ armv7l Raspbian
[   243.258] Current Operating System: Linux pi3-master 4.14.50-v7+ #1122 SMP Tue Jun 19 12:26:26 BST 2018 armv7l
[   243.258] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=480 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=320 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:ProFont6x11 logo.nologo
[   243.258] Build Date: 18 October 2017  04:55:30PM
[   243.258] xorg-server 2:1.19.2-1+rpt1+deb9u2 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[   243.258] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[   243.258]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   243.258] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   243.259] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Sep  8 15:56:59 2018
[   243.274] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   243.274] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   243.283] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   243.283] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   243.283] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   243.283] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   243.290] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[   243.290] (**) |   |-->Device "Allwinner A10/A13/A20 FBDEV"
[   243.290] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   243.290] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   243.290] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   243.290] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   243.290] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   243.306] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   243.306]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   243.313] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[   243.313] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   243.313] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   243.316] (II) Loader magic: 0x1fbf40
[   243.316] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   243.316]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   243.316]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[   243.316]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   243.316]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   243.319] (--) using VT number 2

[   243.319] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[   243.320] (II) no primary bus or device found
[   243.321] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   243.325] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   243.425] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   243.425]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   243.425]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   243.425] (II) LoadModule: "fbturbo"
[   243.427] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbturbo
[   243.427] (II) UnloadModule: "fbturbo"
[   243.427] (II) Unloading fbturbo
[   243.427] (EE) Failed to load module "fbturbo" (module does not exist, 0)
[   243.427] (EE) No drivers available.
[   243.427] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   243.428] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   243.428] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   243.428] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   243.428] (EE) 
[   243.428] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

It seems to me that fbturbo cannot be loaded, but I don't know why.

Comment: *fbturbo cannot be loaded, but I don't know why* because `module does not exist` - it says so, right there at 243.427 - did you follow the instructions in the ebay ad?

Comment: I have tried that instuctions and downloaded the driver and also not worked, and than I downloaded the image, finally it seems to be working